# is there a form alternative to text-area that is multi-line(not like input field)

Tags: php, html, input

I would like to know if there is a multiline textarea you can put in a form that looks like this:

```html
<form action="form.php" method="POST">
    <input name="field2" type="text" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

as you can see, the php script is reliant on the FORM tag, is there any way I can make the textarea actually work in the form like an input element?(what i am trying to do is use php to save a text file server side when button clicked)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Just include the following within the form tags:

```
<textarea name='textfield' placeholder='type your text here'></textarea>
```

Comment: ok, ill try tommorow when I'm not so tired.. jeez I need to sleep

Comment: is there any way to make the placeholder tag show a text file(.txt) in the textarea?

Comment: You will need to use php to open the file and generate the strong, and then echo it as the placeholder text.

Comment: how can you do that plz im desprate!

Comment: Google "return text file as string php" and then give it a try. If you can't figure it out, ask a new stack overflow question.

Comment: well I already asked [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35157500/how-to-display-a-txt-file-in-jquery/35163488#35163488) question...